# Go templates range loop is quoting my value

Tags: go, go-templates

I've got a slice of strings (.Table.PKey.Columns) that I'm trying to loop over in my template to generate a go file that does some appends, but when I output $value in my template, apparently Go is quoting it for me, so it is giving me the error:

```
5:27: expected selector or type assertion, found 'STRING' "ID"
```

i.e., instead of the template output looking something like `o.ID` -- which is what I'm aiming for, it ends up looking something like `o."ID"` (I presume).

Am I right in my assumption that this is the result of using a range loop? Because it seems when I access variables directly in other places (for example, say I had a string and I did: `o.{{.Table.MyString}}`) it works fine, but as soon as I try and incorporate a range loop into the mix it seems to be quoting things.

```
{{- range $key, $value := .Table.PKey.Columns }}
  args = append(args, o.{{$value}})
{{ end -}}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Why did you say you presume? Have you seen the output (ie. before passing it to whatever gives the error you've quoted)?

Comment: And are you using `text/template` or `html/template`?

Comment: Yes, I've seen the output before passing it, there are no quotations in it.

I'm using text/template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{{range}}` does not quote anything. If you see `"ID"` in your output, then your input value *is* `"ID"` with quotation marks included!

See this example:

```
func main() {
    m := map[string]interface{}{
        "Id":     "Id1",
        "Quoted": `"Id2"`,
        "Ids":    []string{"Id1", `"Id2"`, "Abc"},
    }
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(src))
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, m)
}

const src = `{{.Id}} {{index .Ids 0}} {{.Quoted}} 
{{range $key, $value := .Ids}}{{$value}}
{{end}}
`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/CPG-cnX7ro)):

```
Id1 Id1 "Id2" 
Id1
"Id2"
Abc
```

Comment: Weird, I must be doing something wrong elsewhere then. I'll do some more digging. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable Go Template is rendering is within  tags, then Go Template will wrap any strings with quotes for you.

Some options include generating the  in code prior to asking Go Template to render it.